# How to get image from Form and store in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to retrieve an image from a Form, but I always get a `null` instead.

The data is sent from Form as a parameter to the method `AddArticles`, that writes to the database after trying to parse the image into a byte array.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromForm] ArticleViewModel artice, IFormFile file) {
  int result = await AddArticles(artice, file);

  if (result == 201 && ModelState.IsValid) {
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  } else {
    return View(artice);
  }
}

public async Task<int> AddArticles(ArticleViewModel articles, IFormFile file {
  if (articles != null && articles.Name != null && articles.Article != null && articles.category != null) {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    articles.dateTimeOfCreate = dateTime.Date;
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("Article");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<ArticleViewModel>("article");

    if (articles.UrlImage != null) {
      var ArticleModel = new ArticleModel();
      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        articles.UrlImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
        //articles.imagecontext = memoryStream.ToArray();
      }

      await collection.InsertOneAsync(articles);
    }
    return 201;
  } else {
    return 400;
  }
}
```

I want to write the image data into the database. After that, I want to convert that byte array nack into an Image and display it.

```
public class ArticleViewModel {
  [BsonId]
  public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    
  [BsonElement("Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("Article")]
  public string Article { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("Image")]
  public byte[] UrlImage { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("dateTimeOfCreate")]
  public DateTime dateTimeOfCreate { get; set; }

  [BsonElement("Category")]
  public string category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the content type to application/x-www-url-formencoded or application/form-data?

Comment: @rlm96 Yes, but it's not help

Comment: Hi @Key,can you provide your view code?